# Using a repeat loop to look for multiple outliers?

Tags: r, outliers

I'm pretty new to R and am struggling with either a repeat loop, looking for outliers, or both.

I have a large but unreliable data set in the form of a matrix. I'm using the package outliers to search for outliers in the data set, specifically in each row of my matrix of data, however there are multiple outliers for each row. To look for more than one outlier I tried to use a repeat loop to replace outliers (with the row mean) until the standard deviation of the row is under a certain specified value.

```
replaceoutliers <- function(data, standarddeviationthreshold) {
for(k in 1:nrow(data)) {
    repeat{
        data[k,] <- rm.outlier(data[k,], fill=TRUE, median=FALSE, opposite=FALSE)
            if(sd(data[k,]) > standarddeviationthreshold) {
            break
          }
        }
    }
    View(data)
}
```

The function runs, but only replaces the high value in each row. Is there a problem in the repeat loop? Does anyone know of a package that will find and replace multiple outliers? Up to now, I have been unable to fine one.

Thanks!

Edit: I can't share the data I'm using, but this is a test I ran:
I passed the function

```
data <- matrix(c(1:16)^2, nrow=4, ncol=4)
data
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   25   81  169
[2,]    4   36  100  196
[3,]    9   49  121  225
[4,]   16   64  144  256

replaceoutliers(data, 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]     [,4]
[1,]    1   25   81 35.66667
[2,]    4   36  100 46.66667
[3,]    9   49  121 59.66667
[4,]   16   64  144 74.66667
```

So we see the high values being replaced by the mean. However in the first row for example, 1 should also be replaced.

Comment: Normal is data. Forgot to change it, sorry.

Comment: Apparently, `rm.outlier(..., fill=TRUE)` is idempotent.

Comment: So if I change what I use to identify outliers, I should be good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using the `outlier` function directly, to successively remove outliers:

```
replaceoutliers <- function(x, threshold) {
  t(apply(data, 1, function(row) {
    exclude <- rep(FALSE, length(row))
    repeat {
      outliers <- outlier(row[!exclude], logical=TRUE)
      exclude[!exclude] <- outliers
      if (sd(row[!exclude]) < threshold) break
    }
    row[exclude] <- mean(row)
    row
  }))
}
```

Here, outliers are successively removed from the data and replaced with the mean, until the desired standard deviation is breached.

Some notes:

You have the wrong direction for the standard deviation test.  The standard deviation will reduce as you replace outliers with the mean.

`outlier` finds one outlier in the data, the worse value.  Keeping a logical for the removed values allows successive removal while keeping track of the positions of the data.

There is no guarantee that the lower value will be removed on the second iteration.  For the first row, you'll remove the `81` before you remove the `1`.

If you try for too low of a standard deviation, the test fails.  One could code a guard for this, but I did not:

```
> replaceoutliers(data, 50)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   25   81   69
[2,]    4   36  100   84
[3,]    9   49  101  101
[4,]   16   64  120  120
> replaceoutliers(data, 34)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   25   69   69
[2,]    4   36   84   84
[3,]    9   49  101  101
[4,]   16   64  120  120
> replaceoutliers(data, 33)
 Error in if (sd(row[!exclude]) < threshold) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```